# SAS: Is it possible to have SAS check entries across different rows?

Tags: sas, proc-sql

The data I have looks like the picture below. I have the date, the customer name, and the different categories of fruit that they bought.

[image: Example]

I want to **create** a new column that count how many "double sold" occurred. For example, first interaction with customer A is on 1/15, if the second second interaction is within 7 days of the first interaction **and** a fruit is sold, I want it to put a 1 in the "double sold" column.

Essentially, I want SAS to match the customer ID, and then **go down the rows** and look for dates that are within 7 days of the first one.

Comment: What have you tried thus far? It'll help others if you add code for the sample data that others can use without having to program the `datalines` themselves, please. Also why the `sql` and `mysql` tags? Does your solution require these?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I have tried breaking the data apart and move all of the dates with the same ID onto the same row, so that I can use a case when to check along the row, but that wasn't successful because the count of A's is not the same as the count of B's.

Answer (score 0):

Question: why does `ID=C` have `DOUBLE_SOLD=1` in your example? There is no other `ID=C` to compare with. In any case, you'll want to sort by `ID date` and then lag `DATE` by `ID` to make the comparison using simple logic:

```
proc sort data = have;
    by ID DATE;
run;

** edit sales to 1/0 **;
data have1; set have;
    array a(3) APPLE ORANGE PEAR;
    do i=1 to dim(a);
        if a(i)>0 then a(i)=1;
    end;
    drop i;
run;

data want; set have1;
    by ID;
    LAG_DATE=lag(DATE);
        if first.ID then LAG_DATE = .;
        if LAG_DATE ne . then do;
            if (DATE-LAG_DATE)<=7 and sum(APPLE,ORANGE,PEAR)>0 then DOUBLE_SOLD=1;
                else if (DATE-LAG_DATE)>7 or sum(APPLE,ORANGE,PEAR)=0 then DOUBLE_SOLD=0;
        end;
        else do;
            if sum(APPLE,ORANGE,PEAR)>1 then DOUBLE_SOLD=1;
                else DOUBLE_SOLD=0;
        end;
    format LAG_DATE mmddyy10.;
run;
```

Comment: Edited to add condition that if same ID but > 7 days then `DOUBLE_SOLD=0`

Comment: ID = C has double sold, because it sold an apple and a pear.  I already have a working solution for that, so I did not clarify that in the original statement, but if more than 1 fruit are sold on the same day, we also want to set double sold = 1.

Comment: Now you'll want to add a step to make any sales > 1 just equal to 1 so the sum is counting how many different fruits sold. See how that works for you.

Comment: Note that in your last `else do;` statement you'll want the sum > 1 instead of > 0 to indicate more than one fruit sold.

Comment: This code that you are using, is slightly different from the ones I am using. To sort, I would just ORDER BY ID, DATE; What does the very first line, =have do?

Comment: `have` is just a placeholder for what your actual dataset is named. You'll see it on this site often. If your dataset is named `fruits` it'll be `proc sort data = fruits;`.

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you so much!